# What's the meaning of "think into" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in a book, but I don’t understand what it means. The author is a personal coach and is talking about her work with a client:

> A woman I worked with described herself as ‘not a feelings person’ and was convinced there was nothing I could do to help her change this. She was a manager at a restaurant and she had a reputation for giving brutal feedback without realising the impact it had. Thus, she didn’t have the best working relationships she could. I explained: ‘**You can’t think yourself into feeling any more than you can feel yourself into thinking**.’ She looked nonplussed and a bit cross at this, so we started with me helping her with some of the emails she had to write to restaurant staff she had difficult relationships with. I advised her to replace half the ‘I think’ sentences with ‘I feel’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can’t think yourself into feeling any more than you can feel yourself into thinking

To **think yourself into feeling** would be to use intellectual effort into having an emotional response

To **feel yourself into thinking** is the opposite, to use emotional effort to get an intellectual response

The author is saying you can't do either.